# jQueryu ui autocomplete doesn´t show anything in MVC c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to display an autocomplete textbox in a MVC C# View using jQuery-ui autocomplete, this is the code of my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                source: "/Borrar/autocompletar",
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.value);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="container col-md-10 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Autocompletar</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p>
                Empresa: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
```

this is the code of the controller that should populate the textbox

```
 public JsonResult autocompletar(string prefix)
        {
            List<GFC_Site.ViewModels.EmpresaAutocomplete> listado = new List<GFC_Site.ViewModels.EmpresaAutocomplete>();
            ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient cliente = new ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient();
            List<WcfService.Entidades.EmpresaAutocomplete> listadoBase = new List<WcfService.Entidades.EmpresaAutocomplete>();
            listadoBase = cliente.Autocompletar(prefix);
            foreach (var item in listadoBase)
            {
                GFC_Site.ViewModels.EmpresaAutocomplete dato = new ViewModels.EmpresaAutocomplete();
                dato.empresa = item.empresa;
                //dato.np = item.np;
                listado.Add(dato);
            }
            return Json(listado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

where (GFC_Site.ViewModels.EmpresaAutocomplete) is a class with only one string property (empresa) and (ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient cliente) is a connection to a WCF Server, the WCF is the one that connects the application with the database and (List listadoBase) is a class in WCF with two properties(empresa and np).

and this is the method in WCF that retrieve the info that I want to display in the textbox

```
public List<EmpresaAutocomplete> Autocompletar(string prefix)
{
    OdbcCommand cmd = Helper.Commandos.CrearComando();
    cmd.CommandText = "select numero_patronal, nombre_empresa from empresas where estado= ? and nombre_empresa like ?";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@estado", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "1";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empresa", prefix + "%");
    List<EmpresaAutocomplete> data = new List<EmpresaAutocomplete>();
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            EmpresaAutocomplete datos = new EmpresaAutocomplete();
            datos.np = reader["numero_patronal"].ToString();
            datos.empresa = reader["nombre_empresa"].ToString();
            data.Add(datos);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw new ApplicationException("Excepcion :", ex);
    }
    return data;

}
```

well, my problem is that the textbox doesn´t show anything, actually it gets frozen

[image]

could you please tell me what seems for you to be the problem?

Comment: Why did you set `minLength` to 1? How many items would that return? What does the SQL query look like?

Comment: debugging the code, the controller result is correct?

Comment: @Aline yes, it return the due records but the tetxbox doesn´t show them

Comment: Your source property is a route? Your source should be an array of objects, for exemple. What you be searching.. Try to search for: "/"

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397148/jqueryui-autocomplete-render-html-returned-by-server/42401111#42401111

Comment: @Aline already did it but still doesn´t work.

Comment: You never pass a value for `prefix` to the controller (by default its `term`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let’s take take a look at autocomplete in action, starting with a text input:

```
<label for=”somevalue”>Some value:</label><input type=”text” id=”somevalue” name=”somevalue”/>
```

If we add a reference to the jQuery UI script file and css file, we can add a script block to our view:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” language=”javascript”> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(‘#somevalue’).autocomplete({ 
        source: ‘@Url.Action(“Autocomplete”)’ 
    }); 
}) </script>
```

This script block identifies the text input by id and then invokes the autocomplete function to wire up the autocomplete behaviour for this DOM element. We pass a URL to identify the source of the data. For this post I’ve simply created an ASP.NET MVC action that returns JSON data (shown below). Note that in the view I used Url.Action to look up the URL for this action in the routing table – avoid the temptation to hard-code the URL as this duplicates the routing table and makes it hard to change your routing later.

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term) 
{ 
var items = new[] {“Apple”, “Pear”, “Banana”, “Pineapple”, “Peach”};

var filteredItems = items.Where( 
    item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 
    ); 
return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ui-autocomplete/